# Temperature change due to evaporation?

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics

I have a bottle of Dichloromethane (say, 100cc) with air being bubbled through it at a rate of 100 cc/minute at an initial 25 degC. How do I go about determining the rate of change of temperature due to evaporation? [I am assuming only the liquid changes temperature]

Comment: You might start by finding out the partial pressure of Dichlor and its heat of dissociation.  I'm not sure how you'll evaluate the effective area of the surface boundary (of all the bubbles of air), though.

Comment: In reality I will measure it next week using a PT100 with sub-milliKelvin resolution. Just wanted to know what to expect.

Answer (score 2):

The rate of temperature is obviously just the rate of solvent loss due to evaporation multiplied by the latent heat of vapourisation.

The trouble is that I doubt there is any way of estimating the rate of solvent loss without actually doing the experiment. It will be dependent on lots of parameters related to the geometry of your apparatus e.g. bubble size.